# Доступ к роуту /admin в Flask-Admin

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

Помогите настроить модуль Flask-admin.В модуле есть функция для проверки роутов на доступ(например www.yourapp.com/admin/event, но при этом эта функция не работает на просто www.yourapp.com/admin).Как это исправить ?

Comment: Дополните вопрос, о какой функции идёт речь? Что вы подразумеваете под `не работает`?

Answer (score 0):

После раута надо поставить декоратор

```
@cp.route('/pattern_filters', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def pattern_filter():
 pass
```

или для  blueprint

```
@cp.before_request
def before_request():
    if not current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/login')
```